# How to use handler method at another thread on .Net 4.0

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, .net-4.0

Good day!

I try to execute handler method at another thread, but dont know how.

My code:

```
OnMyEvent+=MyTestFunc;


void MyTestFunc(Object sende,SomeClass c)
{
 ... do work;
}
```

Please,tell me how to execute MyTestFunc at another thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest version for a fire and forget method (you don't need any return value) is to use the [Thread Pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y.aspx): [`ThreadPool.QueueUsersWorkItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem.aspx):

```
ThreadPool.QueueUsersWorkItem(_ => MyTestFunc(arg1, arg2));
```

(Use `_` because a state object will be passed, but you don't need it.) If you want to do this for an event handler:

```
OnMyEvent += (x, y) => {
  ThreadPool.QueueUsersWorkItem(_ => MyTestFunc(x, y));
};
```

Comment: **NB** There are better ways of doing this will the [Task Parallel Library (TPL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx), but for simple cases keep it simple.

Comment: And what happens if i have 2 and mode call my event? It will create 2 threads? and when handler mathod ends- shoult thread close?

Comment: @user2545071 read the linked intro to the thread pool: it scales up and down depending on demand.